# Jade / Node.JS not processing JQuery properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Let me start off by saying I have no clue how to debug node.js. I've dabbled in some languages, but not node.js. I'm trying to install a managed package on an Ubuntu 12.04 server and having troubles getting things to work functionally out of the box.

I need to not upgrade past v0.8 node, due to the package.

`node -v : v0.8.0`
`npm -v : 1.1.32`

Here is what I'm getting from Express logging:

```
Error: /home/ubuntu/lobby/views/includes/js/center.jade:4
2| 
3|   jQuery.fn.center = function() {
> 4|     this.css('position', 'absolute');
5|     this.css('top', Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
6|     this.css('left', Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
7|     return this;

unexpected text ;


at Object.Lexer.fail (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:817:11)
at Object.Lexer.next (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:876:15)
at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:114:46)
at Parser.lookahead (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:100:23)
at Parser.peek (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:77:17)
at Parser.tag (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:733:22)
at Parser.parseTag (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:719:17)
at Parser.parseExpr (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:188:21)
at Parser.block (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:689:25)
at Parser.tag (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:806:26)
```

Here is the code for that file:

```
script

jQuery.fn.center = function() {
 this.css('position', 'absolute');
 this.css('top', Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
 this.css('left', Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
return this;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.main').center();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation is critical in jade. It tells jade the hierarchy of the content. By indenting the script contents past the script tag itself, that makes sure that it ends up inside the script tag. Also, more recent versions of jade require "script." for the script tag. I don't remember the reason for it, but the version I pulled from NPM recently got mad at some old jade I wrote without the dot. Try this:

```
script.
  jQuery.fn.center = function() {
   this.css('position', 'absolute');
   this.css('top', Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
   this.css('left', Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
   return this;
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.main').center();
  });
```

Also, I'm not sure there's a good way to debug jade templates. Debugging regular node can be done with console.log() or with an IDE like WebStorm.

Comment: It had the correct indentation but yelled at me, the `script` to `script.` fixed everything for me. Thank you!!!!